# OOP in PHP - variables with methods result in fatal call to member function

Tags: php, oop

I've been trying to find an example or tip on how to do this, and I'm at a loss finding a solution to this issue. I've got two questions - here's the following test code:

```
<?php
class TestClass {
    public $test;

    function __contruct(){

        // this fails:
        //$this->test = (object) array();

        // so does this:
        /*
        $this->test = new stdClass();
        $this->test->hello = function(){
            return 'hello world!';
        };
        */

        $this->test = array();
        $this->test['foo'] = 'bar';
        $this->test['buttons'] = array();
        $this->test['hello'] = function(){
            return 'hello world!';
        };
        $this->test['addButton'] = function($title,$url){
            // how do I call the class' addButton function and
            // pass a reference of the $test varaible so it gets updated?
        };

    }

    // this function would be used for multiple objects
    function addButton(&$obj,$title,$url){
        $obj['buttons'][] = array(
            'title' => $title,
            'url' => $url
        );
    }
}

$myTestClass = new TestClass;
// this results in:
// Fatal error: Call to a member function hello() on null
echo $myTestClass->test->hello();
?>
```

I'd appreciate any feedback you can give on

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change `__contruct` to `__construct`

then make sure to call the function like this `echo $myTestClass->test['hello']();`

calling  `$myTestClass->test->hello();` assumes you have a method called `hello()` in `$test` in your class, which you don't

try this, it works

```
<?php
class TestClass {
    public $test;

    function __construct(){

        // this fails:
        //$this->test = (object) array();

        // so does this:
        /*
        $this->test = new stdClass();
        $this->test->hello = function(){
            return 'hello world!';
        };
        */

        $this->test = array();
        $this->test['foo'] = 'bar';
        $this->test['buttons'] = array();
        $this->test['hello'] = function(){
            return 'hello world!';
        };
        $this->test['addButton'] = function($title,$url){
            // how do I call the class' addButton function and
            // pass a reference of the $test varaible so it gets updated?
        };

    }

    // this function would be used for multiple objects
    function addButton(&$obj,$title,$url){
        $obj['buttons'][] = array(
            'title' => $title,
            'url' => $url
        );
    }
}

$myTestClass = new TestClass;
// this results in:
// Fatal error: Call to a member function hello() on null
echo $myTestClass->test['hello']();
```

Comment: Thanks - that gets me farther along. Is there a way to format it so that I can call $myTestClass->test->hello()?

Also, can you give come guidance on the other question about passing a reference of the variable to the class' addButton function?

Comment: To use `->` you must have __objects__. Make sure you understand difference between array and object.

Comment: @PatFriedl I wouldn't recommend it, you would have to add unnecessary code ... it's not what OOP should do or look like

Comment: Understood - do you have an example of that? if I use (object) array - I get an error that "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".

I've got a project that's requiring a little more php than I know, and I'm trying to come up to speed quickly.

Comment: Ok, I'm coming from clientside, and used to chaining methods in JS and jQuery.

Comment: Chaining is ok but lots of logic in the constructor isn't

Answer (score 0):

You spelled `__construct` wrong. You need to `function __contruct() {}`. Then the constructor will be called and you'll see results. Since you're accessing an array you need to use `[]` syntax on the access. So `echo $myTestClass->test['hello']();`

Furthermore you can do this:

```
$self = $this;
$this->test['addButton'] = function($title,$url) use ($self) {
    // how do I call the class' addButton function and
    // pass a reference of the $test varaible so it gets updated?
    $self->addButton($self, $title, $url);
};
```

Comment: Oops. Ok, fixing that doesn't help - still get the errors.

Comment: In the snippet above, wouldn't I need to call:

 $self->addButton($self->test,$title,$url);